# Best Practice, render same partial multiple times, similar id issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a master-detail-master-detail (order header-> order details-> work order header->Work order details) relationship that I want to show on a single page. I have a standard form to start with the order header, then a series of kendo ui tabs, one for each order detail. Within the tab, I display a partial view showing a nested master detail relationship showing the Work Order Header (form) and Work order Details (grid).

The problem with this is that since the partial is being generated multiple times on the same page, you have non-unique element ids.

All in all, it works, except that it violates non-unique Id rules and since I have some kendo widgets in the partial, they don't work because of this.

So just wondering what is the best way to handle this? I suppose you could put a suffix on each Id, and then capture the form submit and strip the suffix off before the form is submitted to the controller...

Are there any other ways?